# Can I drive in Europe after passing test on provisional license

Tags: driving

I have passed my UK driving test and have been driving for ~ 6 months but have been too lazy to send off for my full license (you have 2 years to do this). Can I drive in Europe without actually possessing a full license?

Comment: You didn't just have it sent to you automatically after your driving test?

Comment: Definitely send off for your full license ASAP, it saves a lot of hassle, you don't even need to change your photo. If you get pulled over by police and they wonder why you're carrying a provisional without L plates, that'll be yours and their time wasted while they're verifying your license. You're still good to drive even when you've posted your provisional back to the DVLA and waiting for your full license, just keen a note of your license number.

Answer (score 2):

According to Gov.UK (link below) you need a Driving Licence - it does not say "or provisional". You should also check your insurance requirements. In addition remember that even though the legal driving age in the UK is 17, this may not be the case in many countries throughout Europe. Most have a minimum driving age of 18.    https://www.gov.uk/driving-abroad